# Query works differently in Mysql 8 rather that in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysql-8.0

Working on migration of a legacy Java Spring product from MySQL 5.7 to MySQL 8 and encountered an interesting observation

There is such a query

```
 SELECT
  r.roomID,
  rt.roomType,
  m.memberID,
  m.memberName,
  m.divisionID,
  d.name,
  g.roomMaxUsers,
  count(c.callID) as participantsNumber
FROM
  Room r
  LEFT JOIN Calls c ON r.roomID = c.roomID
  and c.clientType != 'R'
  LEFT OUTER JOIN bypassing_client bc ON bc.client_guid = c.GUID,
  RoomType rt,
  Member m,
  GConfig g,
  Division d
WHERE
  r.memberID = m.memberID
  AND r.roomID = 68
  AND r.roomTypeID = rt.roomTypeID
  AND m.divisionID = d.divisionId
  AND r.groupID = g.groupID
  AND bc.client_guid IS NULL
```

Which produces different results in MySQL 5.7 and 8
The correct output is expected to be an empty set in the test case I've checked, due to the condition on `bypassing_client`.
However, in **MySQL 5.7** looks like it returns the first row before the `bc.client_guid IS NULL` condition is applied.

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
            roomID: 68
          roomType: Private
          memberID: 11
        memberName: Peter
        divisionID: 22
              name: Flower
      roomMaxUsers: 10
participantsNumber: 0
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

For the **MySQL 8** the exact same query returns a row with all null values

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
            roomID: NULL
          roomType: NULL
          memberID: NULL
        memberName: NULL
        divisionID: NULL
              name: NULL
      roomMaxUsers: NULL
participantsNumber: 0
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Which is closer to the truth.
I have figured out if I remove `count(c.callID) as participantsNumber` I will get the empty set for both MySQL versions. The aggregative function without a GROUP BY looks odd, but it runs, just produces counter-intuitive result.
The question is why the `count(c.callID) as participantsNumber` is messing up the result and doing it differently for the two MySQL versions?

UDP: in response to @Bill Karwin
**MySQL 5.7**

```
SELECT @@sql_mode;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @@sql_mode                                                                                                                                |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**MySQL 8**

```
SELECT @@sql_mode;
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @@sql_mode                                                                                                            |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Can you run `SELECT @@sql_mode;` on both of your MySQL instances?

Comment: Edited the question with the results, thanks

Comment: Are you sure that `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is in effect at the time you run the query? Your query should result in an error on both versions of MySQL: _"If a query has aggregate functions and no GROUP BY clause, it cannot have nonaggregated columns in the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY enabled"_ (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html).

Comment: I'm not sure if it's related, but another weird thing about your query is that you are mixing SQL-92 `JOIN` syntax with older comma-style joins. This can produce unexpected errors. I suggest using `JOIN` syntax consistently for all your joins.

Comment: Tried to rewrite the query to the "newer" JOIN statements - same result